# Got string with single backslashes (!) in Lua that need to be escaped or replaced - How to?

Tags: string, lua, escaping

In Adobe Lightroom a Plug-in is written in Lua. In an attempt to teach myself Lua I am working myself through the SDK producing own Plug-ins.
Now I came accross a situation where I am getting a string from a table named 'images' like this:

```
images[1] = "d:\Windows\Temp\LREXPORT\NK119542.tif"
```

But of course Lua does not like those unescaped backslashes at all. The content of this table varies depending on the user action. I am thinking of a solution to grab that string and manipulate it for further processing.

Correct strings would be:

```
newimages = "d:/Windows/Temp/LREXPORT/NK119542.tif"
newimages = "d:\\Windows\\Temp\\LREXPORT\\NK119542.tif"
```

Went through lots of posts and online tutorials but sorry, I was not able to figure this one out.
Hope there is a solution, thanks for replies.

Comment: Where are you "getting the string" from? How does Lua print it?

Comment: string comes from a table created with Lightroom SDK 2.0 Syntax

Comment: So if it's already in the table, what's the problem? You say "Lua does not like those unescaped backslashes at all." Why do you say that? What error are you seeing?

Comment: I need that string for further processing.  This command will not be executed:  LrShell.openFilesInApp({"D:\Windows\Temp\LREXPORT\NK121905.tif"}, "c:/Program Files/Adobe/Photoshop.exe")  So I need to escape the backslashes somehow.

Comment: Escaping strings only matters for string *literals*. Once you have the string as a Lua string, it can contain any sequence of characters you want.

Comment: Right, except unescaped Backslashes.
I am seeking a way to replace those Backslashes. The command will NOT execute WITH the Bachslashes, it will when they're escaped or replaced with forward slashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your fine with forward slashes, why not just replace them:

```
images[i]=images[i]:gsub("\\","/")
```

Same goes if you think doubling them will help you:

```
images[i]=images[i]:gsub("\\","\\\\")
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not solve this problem. The issue here is that there are a only single Backslashes in the string, not doubles that would be easy to deal with.

Comment: The code I passed you takes the single backslashes out and puts in doubles. Anyhow, I don't see your problem.

Comment: @snahl: I might be a bit too late but here they used double backslashes to represent one plain backslash. So it does work with your case.

Answer (score 6):

You can delimit your string with `[[` and `]]`:

```
Lua 5.2.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> s = '\n'
> print(s)


> s = [[\n]]
> print(s)
\n
```

Comment: Can I say that the only usage of `\\` in Lua is to represent some special control characters?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and for me this worked:

```
user = string.gsub(user, "\\\\", "/")
```

so `images[i]=images[i]:gsub("\\\\","/")` should work as well.